# SwiftUI updating array state doesn't update view

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

Here is my test code:

```
struct ArrView: View {
    @State var arr: [String] = ["first", "second"]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("append") {self.arr.append("item\(self.arr.count)")}
            List(arr.indices) {row in
                Text(self.arr[row])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the 'append' Button was pressed, the `List` view didn't update.
Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding `.id(self.arr.count)` after list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ForEach<Range>()` only if the provided data is a constant, otherwise you need to use `ForEach(_:id:content:)` and provide an `id` explicitly, like this:

```swift
struct ArrView: View {
    @State var arr: [String] = ["first", "second"]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("append") {self.arr.append("item\(self.arr.count)")}
            List(arr, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is the proper way to create `List` view. Here is a sample

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var arr: [String] = ["first", "second"]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("append") {self.arr.append("item\(self.arr.count)")}
            List(self.arr, id: \.self) { str in
                Text(str)
            }
        }
    }
}
```