# Updating state for an element of a @Published array, doesn't refresh the view

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, state, swiftui-list

I have the following LocationToggleable class, which I have attempted to make an observable object, as well as a struct, and various other attempts. This object is being maintained by a `LocationService` class, which is also an `ObservableObject` and it's being published in an `[LocationToggleable]` array. I understand that updating the state for an individual element of that array, doesn't necessarily publish the updates from that element, because the array itself wasn't actually updated, merely a property of an element of the array. How do I properly update a list, when a property is changed, on a `@Published` array?

#### Failed Attempts

```swift
class LocationToggleable: Hashable, Identifiable {
    // Omitted unrelated properties
    var selected: Bool = false
}

class LocationToggleable: ObservableObject, Hashable, Identifiable {
    // Omitted unrelated properties
    @Published var selected: Bool = false
}

struct LocationToggleable: Hashable, Identifiable {
    // Omitted unrelated properties
    var selected: Bool = false
}
```

#### Location Service

```swift
class LocationService: ObservableObject {
    //Omitted unrelated properties/functions
    @Published var toggleableLocations: [LocationToggleable]
}

class LocationService: ObservableObject {
    //Omitted unrelated properties/functions
    @StateObject var toggleableLocations: [LocationToggleable]
}

class LocationService: ObservableObject {
    //Omitted unrelated properties/functions
    @ObservedObject var toggleableLocations: [LocationToggleable]
}
```

#### List

- Partial Code, the else is just a copy of the true return

```swift
ForEach(locationService.toggleableLocations, id: \.self) { item in
                            if item.selected {
                                Section(content: {}, header: {
                                    TrailDetailCardView(location: item.location)
                                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "location-id-\(item.id)", in: namespace)
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            withAnimation {
                                                proxy.scrollTo(item.id, anchor: UnitPoint(x: 0, y: 0.01))
                                                locationService.setSelected(for: item, to: !item.selected)
                                            }
                                        }
                                })
                                .id(item.id)
                            }
```

#### Set Selected Function

- This works right now, but that's only because I'm forcing a publish update for the `toggleableLocations` and it reeks of a code-smell.

```swift
    func setSelected(for toggleableLocation: LocationToggleable, to selected: Bool) {
        if let currentIndex = toggleableLocations.firstIndex(where: { $0.selected }) {
            toggleableLocations[currentIndex].selected = false
        }
        toggleableLocation.selected = selected
        toggleableLocations = toggleableLocations
    }
```

#### Notes

- [SwiftUI updating array state doesn't update view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62046829/swiftui-updating-array-state-doesnt-update-view) This solution doesn't work in my case, because I need the object to maintain it's `selected` state for proper management of it's layout in the `LazyVGrid`. I also need the object to be `Hashable` for uses elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Only 2 wrappers work inside ObservableObjects. Published and AppStorage. You have to use wrappers in a View or a DynamicProperty every ObservableObject has to be wrapped at every level. But everything changes with iOS 17

Comment: @loremipsum I am currently wrapping `locationService` with `@ObservedObject` at every level it's being used at. I think in a nutshell, updating that property `selected` on an element of the `toggleableLocations` doesn't update the view, despite it being wrapped with `@ObservedObject`. So is there a specific way I need to trigger that update for the array, on element property change? I'm not sure what `@DynamicProperty` would be and documentation on Apple is sparse on it.

Comment: Your wrappers are in a class they only work in a View. Only 2 work in a class, ObservedObject and StateObject don’t.

Comment: The DynamicProperty thing is a caveat but doesn’t  really apply here, the issue is your use of property wrappers in the wrong spot.

Comment: To solve your issues, you need to understand how to use `ObservableObject`.
Have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app:  [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)  Just copy and paste the appropriate example and adapt to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this approach as shown in the example code, to `...properly update a list, when a property is changed, on a @Published array`.

The example code uses one `@StateObject var locationService = LocationService()`, the source of data truth.
It also uses the `$` sign in the `ForEach` to allow changes to be made to the `item`,
and a simple `item.selected.toggle()` to toggle the selection.

```
struct LocationToggleable: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()  // <--- here
    // Omitted unrelated properties
    var selected: Bool
    var location: String  // <--- for testing
}

class LocationService: ObservableObject {
    //Omitted unrelated properties/functions
    @Published var toggleableLocations: [LocationToggleable] = [
        LocationToggleable(selected: true, location: "location-1"),
        LocationToggleable(selected: false, location: "location-2"),
        LocationToggleable(selected: true, location: "location-3")]  // <--- here for testing, else []
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var locationService = LocationService() // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach($locationService.toggleableLocations) { $item in  // <--- here $
            if item.selected {
                Section(content: {}, header: {
                    TrailDetailCardView(location: item)  // <--- here
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                       // .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "location-id-\(item.id)", in: namespace)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation {
//                                proxy.scrollTo(item.id, anchor: UnitPoint(x: 0, y: 0.01))
                                item.selected.toggle()  // <--- here
                            }
                        }
                })
                .id(item.id)
            } 
            // --- for testing
            else {
                Text("\(item.location) not selected").id(item.id)
                    .onTapGesture {item.selected.toggle() }
            }
            
        }
    }
}


// for testing
struct TrailDetailCardView: View {
    var location: LocationToggleable // <--- here, use @Binding if required
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(location.selected ? "true" : "false").border(.red)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The trick was to change the element to a `struct`, then use `@StateObject` in my implementation, using a `binding` in the `ForEach`. I learned something new today, I didn't even know I could use a binding in a `ForEach`.